# How can I install Ubuntu 13.10 on a Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite? (screen turns off)

Tags: system-installation, uefi, samsung

I already tried to with install Ubuntu 13.10 on my Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite with the `UEFI and CMS OS` option in the BIOS, but I still have the same problem. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 from a USB drive. The Grub menu appears, so when I click on the first or second options, in both cases I see the startup screen, and then the screen turns off and nothing happens after that.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make a bootdisk with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Boot up from disk and run tool. Violá! ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It was an ATI driver isue, i used a Linuxmint livecd and hadn't problem to install. Now my laptop runs Olivia xfce.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion by Heriberto. Install the using a Linux Mint live USB with xfce.

This can be found [here](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=156).